# how to pass data sing postLink in cakphp 2.0

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to know how to fetch request data by postlink in cakephp 2.0.

```
echo $this->Html->div('col-md-12', $this->Form->postLink(__($a['b']['name'].'abc'), array('controller' => 'abc', 'action' => 'xyz', $a['b']['slug'], $a['b']['id']), array($a['b']['id'])));
```

In output I want value for '$a['b']['slug']'.
i.e. pr($a['b']['slug']);
o/p : xyz

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way(as per my knowledge) but you can still do it another way using javascript,

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="postForm" action="/action_page/55?data=Your_data" hidden>
</FORM>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Enter',
['onClick' => 'document.postForm.submit();return false']); ?>
```

As per my knowledge, this is an alternative solution to your question. I think there are no direct ans to your ques.